# Why is this while loop entering infinite state instead of stopping after 3 iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find out if the word guessed is correct. After 3 wrong attempts it is entering infinite loop. Why is the while loop not ending after 3rd iteration?

```python
secret_word = "python"
guess = ""
attempt = 1

while guess != secret_word:
    if attempt < 3:
        guess = input("your word: ")
        attempt += 1

    else:
        print("time up!")

print("win!")
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Also, why would your loop ever end? There's nothing that would make it stop.

Comment: Because you need to add break in your else block. please next time post the code in your question instead of link.

Comment: If your edit of someone else's closed question does not bring it to the level of reopening it, then please do not edit at all @timgeb. It only creates extra work for reviewers.

Comment: I support @Broman . Although the edit itself did not have to be reviewed (editor having full edit privileges), it did cause this question to enter the Reopen queue. In its current form, it is not fit to be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `attemp >= 3`, your while loop starts executing the `else` clause. The thing is the loop doesn't finish because, as the user hasn't guessed, guess is not equal to secret_word.

One way you could fix it is adding a `break` statement after `print('time up!')`. However, that would also print `'win'`. To prevent that last bit, wrap the `print('win')` in an `else` statement turning:

```
print('win')
```

Into:

```
else:
    print('win')
```

An else condition in a while loop is executed if the loop has exited normally (with the condition being false), and not by a `break` statement or an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
secret_word = 'python'
attempts = 3

for attempt in range(attempts):
    guess = input(f'Attempt {attempt+1}: ')
    if guess == secret_word:
        print('You won!')
        break
    else:
        print('try again...')
```

Comment: Please explain in words what was wrong in the original question, and why this solution solves the problem.